# Spring Boot with basic auth enabled not returning 401 when run with Tomcat in docker

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, tomcat, war

I have a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class with

```
    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and().csrf().disable()
    }
```

when running locally with `bootRun`, this results in a 401 and `WWW-Authenticate: Basic` header which results in my browser prompting basic auth login. When I build a war and deploy it in a Tomcat Docker container, however, I no longer get the 401 and instead get a 500 due to a global controller advice which expects an authentication context.

I added logbook to try to help me debug what's going on but when the `logbook-spring-boot-starter` dependency is added, I started getting the behavior I expected - a 401 response with the `WWW-Authenticate: Basic` header.

Comparing the logs with and without `logbook-spring-boot-starter` and when running locally, the relevant lines seem to be:

**WITHOUT** `logbook-spring-boot-starter`

```
"FORWARD" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
```

**WITH** `logbook-spring-boot-starter`

```
Cannot forward to error page for request [/] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false
```

Locally:

```
Securing GET /error
```

So it seems like on auth error, Spring Boot is redirecting to `/error` and I'm seeing that:

- locally with bootRun, the /error endpoint is also secured and attempting to hit it results in a 401 and browser login prompt
- in the Tomcat container, the /error endpoint ISN'T secured? and this results in the global controller advice running and resulting in a null pointer exception
- in the Tomcat container WITH `logbook-spring-boot-starter`, the behavior is the same as the above except that the addition of logbook seems to commit the 401 response for the initial request before the forwarding can be completed.

What explains the difference in behavior between running locally and from the WAR?

Full logs below

Tomcat Docker War **WITHOUT** `logbook-spring-boot-starter`

```
2022-06-01 06:02:59.794  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-06-01 06:02:59.795 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
2022-06-01 06:02:59.795 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver
2022-06-01 06:02:59.795 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected FixedThemeResolver
2022-06-01 06:02:59.797 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@50a0cb0d
2022-06-01 06:02:59.798 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@76a481a
2022-06-01 06:02:59.798 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2022-06-01 06:02:59.799  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 4 ms
2022-06-01 06:02:59.812 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /
2022-06-01 06:02:59.820 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2022-06-01 06:02:59.826 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2022-06-01 06:02:59.826 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.session.SessionManagementFilter  : Request requested invalid session id 53075EC9BB90BEDFC113FBEF9513C524
2022-06-01 06:02:59.837 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Failed to authorize filter invocation [GET /] with attributes [authenticated]
2022-06-01 06:02:59.862 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8080/ to session
2022-06-01 06:02:59.862 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]
2022-06-01 06:02:59.862 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : No match found. Using default entry point org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint@7a5b37af
2022-06-01 06:02:59.863 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
2022-06-01 06:02:59.866 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
2022-06-01 06:02:59.866 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2022-06-01 06:02:59.874 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "FORWARD" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
2022-06-01 06:02:59.882 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2022-06-01 06:02:59.928 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Unresolved failure from "FORWARD" dispatch: java.lang.NullPointerException: getContext().authentication must not be null
2022-06-01 06:02:59.936 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter  : Forwarding to error page from request [/] due to exception [getContext().authentication must not be null]

java.lang.NullPointerException: getContext().authentication must not be null
```

Tomcat Docker War **WITH** `logbook-spring-boot-starter`

```
2022-06-01 06:08:35.498  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-06-01 06:08:35.499 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
2022-06-01 06:08:35.499 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver
2022-06-01 06:08:35.499 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected FixedThemeResolver
2022-06-01 06:08:35.500 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@86ba7b4
2022-06-01 06:08:35.501 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@1f27d56d
2022-06-01 06:08:35.501 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2022-06-01 06:08:35.501  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
2022-06-01 06:08:35.582 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /
2022-06-01 06:08:35.591 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2022-06-01 06:08:35.597 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2022-06-01 06:08:35.598 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.session.SessionManagementFilter  : Request requested invalid session id 53075EC9BB90BEDFC113FBEF9513C524
2022-06-01 06:08:35.611 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Failed to authorize filter invocation [GET /] with attributes [authenticated]
2022-06-01 06:08:35.632 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8080/ to session
2022-06-01 06:08:35.632 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]
2022-06-01 06:08:35.632 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : No match found. Using default entry point org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint@46412af4
2022-06-01 06:08:35.633 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
2022-06-01 06:08:35.635 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
2022-06-01 06:08:35.635 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2022-06-01 06:08:35.714 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter  : Cannot forward to error page for request [/] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false
```

local `bootRun` **WITHOUT** `logbook-spring-boot-starter`

```
2022-05-31 23:14:21.245  INFO 6611 --- [nio-8040-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-05-31 23:14:21.245  INFO 6611 --- [nio-8040-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-05-31 23:14:21.245 DEBUG 6611 --- [nio-8040-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
2022-05-31 23:14:21.245 DEBUG 6611 --- [nio-8040-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver
2022-05-31 23:14:21.245 DEBUG 6611 --- [nio-8040-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected FixedThemeResolver
2022-05-31 23:14:21.246 DEBUG 6611 --- [nio-8040-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@b5c7e59
2022-05-31 23:14:21.247 DEBUG 6611 --- [nio-8040-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@6e3bfa0e
2022-05-31 23:14:21.247 DEBUG 6611 --- [nio-8040-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2022-05-31 23:14:21.247  INFO 6611 --- [nio-8040-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
2022-05-31 23:14:21.255 DEBUG 6611 --- [nio-8040-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /
2022-05-31 23:14:21.260 DEBUG 6611 --- [nio-8040-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2022-05-31 23:14:21.263 DEBUG 6611 --- [nio-8040-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2022-05-31 23:14:21.263 DEBUG 6611 --- [nio-8040-exec-1] o.s.s.w.session.SessionManagementFilter  : Request requested invalid session id 789A68B0872355A7EC94D1AFCBAFBEFB
2022-05-31 23:14:21.269 DEBUG 6611 --- [nio-8040-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Failed to authorize filter invocation [GET /] with attributes [authenticated]
2022-05-31 23:14:21.285 DEBUG 6611 --- [nio-8040-exec-1] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8040/ to session
2022-05-31 23:14:21.285 DEBUG 6611 --- [nio-8040-exec-1] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]
2022-05-31 23:14:21.285 DEBUG 6611 --- [nio-8040-exec-1] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : No match found. Using default entry point org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint@350be64b
2022-05-31 23:14:21.286 DEBUG 6611 --- [nio-8040-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
2022-05-31 23:14:21.287 DEBUG 6611 --- [nio-8040-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
2022-05-31 23:14:21.287 DEBUG 6611 --- [nio-8040-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2022-05-31 23:14:21.289 DEBUG 6611 --- [nio-8040-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error
2022-05-31 23:14:21.289 DEBUG 6611 --- [nio-8040-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2022-05-31 23:14:21.289 DEBUG 6611 --- [nio-8040-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2022-05-31 23:14:21.289 DEBUG 6611 --- [nio-8040-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /error
2022-05-31 23:14:21.300 DEBUG 6611 --- [nio-8040-exec-1] a.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator : filter invocation [/error] denied for AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=AE0C802AD2AE3350FF6C045960747CCD], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
```

Comment: Looks like some version mixed up. Which version of Spring boot and Tomcat are you running? And, is there any reason why you don't want to use the embedded Tomcat?

Comment: @grekier I should have included this in the question originally, but this is with Spring Boot `2.6.7` and the `tomcat:9-jre17-temurin` docker image. Not sure why it didn't occur to me that I should just use the embedded Tomcat and deploy a JAR to a typical linux container as opposed to a WAR in a Tomcat container.. I'll try that

Comment: That worked! Still curious to know what happened here though. Will investigate more tomorrow

Comment: Since the tomcat version seems to be almost the same (9.0.62 vs 9.0.63), I would guess it has to do with some tomcat security config in the default docker image.

Comment: @grekier but the logs coming from Spring Boot seem to suggest that the issue is related to the request being forwarded to `/error` and how that's handled differently

Comment: Might be that security manager is disable in default tomcat container or a Filter handling Exception differently. I do not know but there probably may be 50 different reasons in the difference between configurations.